# Using Scanner class in java to print X1-X3+X5....n

Tags: java, class, wolfram-mathematica, series

I was trying to print the following series: 
X<sup>1</sup>-X<sup>3</sup>+X<sup>5</sup>-X<sup>7</sup>.......X<sup>n</sup>

I have done everything but struck on changing the sign.
Anybody has idea?

Here is the code:

```
int n=10;int sum=0;int x=2;

double d=0.00;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    d = Math.pow(x,i);
    sum = sum + (int)d;
}
```

Comment: Can you just use an if statement and check if i is even? if(i%2==0){use minus}else{use plus}?

Comment: Use Math.pow(-1,i-1) in your loop

Comment: just add  Math.pow(-1,i-1) as @LokeshAgrawal said!

Comment: where did you use `Scanner` class in this code?

Answer (score 0):

you should do some steps:

### First way

- use a `boolean` and name it as `SIGN`

  - change it's value each time you reach end of loop to determine sign based on 1 or 0 (true or false)

    - if `sign` was `true` use `+`
    - if `sign` was `false` use `-`
- increase `i` in for loop twice (`i+=2`) each time, so values of `i` will be `1, 3, 5, ...`

---

```
int n=10;int sum=0;int x=2;

double d=0.00;
boolean sign = true;
for(int i=1; i<=n ; i+=2 ){
    d=Math.pow(x,i);
    sum += ((sign)?(int)d:(-1*(int)d));
    sign = !sign;
}
```

### Second way

- use an `integer` and name it as `SIGN`

  - change it's value each time you reach end of loop to determine sign based on 1 or -1.
- since it has the same type as the iterator variable, you can define it in the loop.

---

```
int n=10;int sum=0;int x=2;

for (int i = 1, sign = 1; i <= n; i += 2, sign = -sign) {
    sum += sign * (int)Math.pow(x, i);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `int sign=1`, `sum += sign * (int)d;`, and `sign = -sign;` be easier?

Comment: @Andreas please check my answer, if it needs edit, please do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can input parameters by `Scanner` and change the sign by `Math.pow(-1,n)`.
code is as follows.

```
int sum = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter n:");
int n = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("please enter x:");
int x = input.nextInt();
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i += 2){
    sum += (int)Math.pow(-1, (i-1)/2) * Math.pow(x, i);
}
```